# Let $m$ be a finite Borel measure on a metric space $(X,d)$. Show $\displaystyle\lim_{\rho \to r}m(B_x(\rho)) = m(B_x(r))$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $m$ be a finite Borel measure on a metric space $(X,d)$. Prove that for any $x\in X$ and $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a number $0<r<\epsilon$ such that 
$$\displaystyle\lim_{\rho \to r}m(B_x(\rho)) = m(B_x(r)).$$

I think the proof need the identity $m(\cup_nA_n)=\lim_nm(A_n)$ and $m(\cap_nB_n=\lim_m(B_n))$, where $A_n$ is a nondecreasing sequence of measurable sets and $B_n$ is a non increasing sequence of measurable sets. I don't know how to use them. Do I need to construct a sequcence of measurable sets?

Comment: No. You need to observe that this will hold if $\{ y: d(y,x)=r \}$ has measure zero (dominated convergence), and this can fail for at most countably many $r>0$, or the measure wouldn't be finite.